# how or if could I ship helvetica or similar fonts with my web-app?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a web-app (Java/HTML based) on cloud.  Client will be accessing it in IE/Chrome or Mozilla.

I want to use Helvetica or any similar fonts but they are, by default, not available in systems (windows/IE/Chrome/Mozilla).  Is there a way I can ship these fonts with my project?

Secondly are there any good free similar ones, which dont require licensing? 
But most importantly, how is it possible technically?  Do I put that as resource in my web-app? If yes, how? and would it then prompt users to download or install it - because thats a no (we cant ship installables with this product).

Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with cloud based things, but if you can use CSS can't you use `@font-face`?

Comment: Try google fonts. (open sans, roboto)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a license for the font, you can't include it with your project.

You can use something like

1. [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) - free
2. [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) - free. [Option to include fonts](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) that you have licenses for.
3. [Type Kit](https://typekit.com/fonts) - different licensing options.

Font Squirrel is a good way to "package" it because it is just CSS + files for the fonts, as the others are cloud-based. You can filter by "web fonts" and then download the "Web Font Kit" which has everything you need. Easy!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip.  Is there any Helvetica like font available you might know in Font Squirrel - free as well as paid?

Comment: @Tintin Best thing to do is to use the filters on Font Squirrel to narrow down fonts you'd be interested in. [Like this](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?filter[classification]=sans+serif&=&filter[license][web]=Y&filter[family_size]=1&filter[download]=all&sort=a2z) which is filtering by sans-serif web fonts.

Answer (score 1):

To complement MikeSmithDev’s answer with a technical point: You can use the `@font-face` technique (described on many pages also frequently asked about at SO) just as you would on a web page, but you need not refer to font files in a server. You can simply include the .wof, .eot etc. files in the application package and refer to them with relative URLs, as in

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
body { font-family: Source Sans Pro }
```

Although expressions like “downloadable fonts” and “web fonts” are often used, the technique works fine this way, too, without needing any download (apart from getting the application of course) or Internet connection when using the application.

So the user will not be prompted for allowing download, and he does not need to install the fonts; they are directly used by the browser.

Comment: +1 for the technical stuff I was referring to and clarifying the download prompt concern. I typically don't like link-only answers and here I am giving one.